How can I increase the survival cycle of an object moving from young generation to old generation heap space in java
I have a spring boot application development which is processing an memory intensive process for an amount of time which is let than 5 mins. It will create lots of objects created and it will be destroyed at the end of the processing time. During this time those objects are getting moved from young generation memory to old generation as it's survived some number of GC cycle.
I need to control this since it's not necessary to have the unused memory reference object in the old generation memory.
Could anyone please help me on how to configure the GC ARGUMENTS SO THAT the minimum lifetime objects should not be moved to old generation Heap space?

Why do you think you need to take control manual control of a language that is designed to take that control away from developers? In what manner is the scenario that you described causing an issue?

What do you mean with “the unused memory reference object in the old generation memory”? The garbage collector does not move unused objects into the old generation. It only deals with objects still in use. Depending on what garbage collector you’ve chosen, the “move to old generation” just means considering a memory region containing some objects “old generation” from that time on, without any actual cost.

Young generation moving cycle to Old gen depends on the size availability of the Young generation.
You can configure the below params to do that.
The size of the young and old generation can be contolled by NewRatio. Also, you need to specify parameters NewSize and MaxNewSize for the young generation size.
Another parameter SurvivorRatio can be used to tune the size of the survivor spaces.
For example, -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 sets the ratio between eden and a survivor space to 1:4. i.e if your Young Gen is size of 4, the for 2 survivor spaces you have 1 space each(total 2 space).

You may want to use -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold JVM parameter, which will determine how many minor GCs an object can survive, before it is promoted to old generation from young generation.
Its value can range from 0 - 15.
Caveat - If the value set is too low, it may lead to premature promotion of short-lived objects, which eventually would lead to Stop The World (STW) GCs for reclaiming objects from Old Generation.
